# Are kitten specific foods legit?

Tags: cats, diet

Are kitten specific cat foods, like [Lara Junior](http://www.versele-laga.com/en/lara/Products/lara-junior), really better for kittens than adult labeled cat foods, or it's just a marketing gimmick?

Comment: you need to take a look  at the nutritional value of kitten food and compare it with food for adult cats,the result will be kitten food contains more protein and fat than food made for adult cats.so it is legit but it is in no way dangerous for a kitten to eat food for adult cats.